# Visual Studio 2022 MsTest not allowing step-in debugging

Tags: unit-testing, .net-6.0, visual-studio-2022

I've recently upgraded Visual Studio 2019 to Visual Studio 2022 and am upgrading an old project from .Net Core 3.1 to .Net 6.0. The upgrade worked fine, but I ran into a problem with unit tests. I use MSTest. When using Visual Studio 2019 if I put breakpoints inside the test method, right clicked inside that method, and then selected debug, it would allow me to step through each breakpoint (using F10 or F11 to move ahead). But in 2022 when I do the same it runs the whole test without hitting any of the breakpoints (just like I would expect if I selected Run instead of Debug). How can I do a step-in step-by-step debugging with MS Test Unit in VS 2022?

(Below is a sample of a unit test I created. It runs with no errors, it just doesn't let me do the step-in debugging).

```
[TestClass]
public class UnitTest1
{

    private readonly IApiManager api;

    public UnitTest1(IApiManager api)
    {
        this.api = api;
    }


    [TestMethod]
    public void TestMethod1()
    {

        string data1 = "test data";
        string data2 = "test data 2";

        api.PassData(data1, data2);

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The presence of a constructor causes this behavior. Removing it and moving the injections into each test class itself will fix this.