Create C# Visual Studio 2022 Launch Profile to debug native code, when starting from MSTest
I am using a native library in a C# application, and I need to step into some of the native functions for debugging.  C# project is ASP.NET on Visual Studio 2022.
I have configured this project's launch profile for "IIS Express" to "Enable native code Debugging" and it works: I can step into native function when launching performing an action in a browser.
I am trying to do the same (i.e step into native code) when attempting test parts of the application from MSTest project.  I imagine that I have to setup a different type of launch profile for launching from MS test.  Anyone ever figured out how to do this?  I tried setting up a profile but i couldn't make the native debug work.
PS: I enabled native code (or "mixed mode") debugging for each of the launch profiles available out of the box (http, https, IIS Express, Docker).

You need to check the code of "(i.e step into native code)" separately. The presence of a constructor causes this behavior. Removing it and moving the injections into each test class itself will fix this. For details, please check similar cases:https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75587061/visual-studio-2022-mstest-not-allowing-step-in-debugging?rq=2
